# How to create an applet for cinnamon Linux Mint 17.1 downloaded applications

Tags: applet, zip, panel, tar, linux-mint

Some applications like `PostMan, SpringToolSuite etc.` which has to be downloaded in `tar.gz, .zip files` from official websites would give a hard time in setting up applets for quick access on the Linux Mint panel.

So after cracking my head for 3 to 4 hours. I was able to create applet for faster access using this method.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this problem for most of the applications that I downloaded from tar.gz and zip file Linux Mint doesn't automatically create an applet that can be used for quick access.
But on the contrary, deb files that are executable on double-click can automatically create applet for quick access as it compiles with help of package installer.

So the solution that I followed is:

1. Extract the compressed package which generates a folder.
2. Right click and choose the option Create a new launcher here...
3. Select the name and select the main executable provided in the
   generated folder.
4. This would create a rocket icon launcher(as of Linux Mint 17.1)
5. Right Click that icon and open in text-editor add this line
   Icon=/icon-location..
6. Click on Menu type the rocket icon launcher Name that you given in
   step 3
7. Right click on the result that has rocket icon launcher, add to
   panel

That's it!!